# submitting form from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms

how can i submit a form on enter pressed while i amm typing in textarea........if i hit enter it only breaks a line but not submits the form.

Comment: This is technically unexpected behavior. People expect to see a line-return when they press enter from within a textarea. I would encourage you to re-think what it is you're doing.

Comment: Agree with Jonathan, you could, however, submit the form if they hit ctrl+enter or some other modifier. Outlook does just that to send emails, warning you the first time you use that shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<textarea onkeypress="handleKeyEvent(event);">`

```
function handleKeyEvent(e) {
    var charCode;

    if (e && e.which) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else if (window.event) {
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if (charCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
    }
}
```

But I'd advise against such a thing, or at least make sure that users know what will happen when they press enter. Generally they expect a line break.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to use JavaScript. Roughly speaking:

- Put an `onkeypress` event handler on the `textarea`
- In the event handler, [check whether the key that was pressed is enter](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)
- If so, call the `submit` function of the form

Alternatively, use `<input type="text">` instead of `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/stringEnterKeyDetector.html

Use the javascript function:

```
function checkEnter(e) {
  //if which property of event object is supported (NN4)
  if(e && e.which) {
    //character code is contained in NN4's which property
    characterCode = e.which;
  }
  else {
    e = event;
    //character code is contained in IE's keyCode property
    characterCode = e.keyCode;
  }

  //if generated character code is equal to ascii 13 (if enter key)
  if(characterCode == 13) {
    //submit the form
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }  
}
```

And then use the following on your textarea:

```
<textarea onKeyPress="checkEnter(event)">
```